# HDFStore.append(string, DataFrame) fails when string column contents are longer than those already there

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I have a Pandas DataFrame stored via an HDFStore that essentially stores summary rows about test runs I am doing.

Several of the fields in each row contain descriptive strings of variable length.

When I do a test run, I create a new DataFrame with a single row in it:

```
def export_as_df(self):
    return pd.DataFrame(data=[self._to_dict()], index=[datetime.datetime.now()])
```

And then call `HDFStore.append(string, DataFrame)` to add the new row to the existing DataFrame.

This works fine, apart from where one of the string columns contents is larger than the longest instance already existing, whereupon I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-302-a33c7955df4a>", line 516, in save_pytables
store.append('tests', test.export_as_df())
File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 532, in append
self._write_to_group(key, value, table=True, append=True, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 788, in _write_to_group
s.write(obj = value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2491, in write
min_itemsize=min_itemsize, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2254, in create_axes
raise Exception("cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->%s,items->%s] %s" % (b.dtype.name, b.items, str(detail)))
Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object,items->Index([bp, id, inst, per, sp, st, title], dtype=object)] [values_block_3] column has a min_itemsize of [51] but itemsize [46] is required!
```

I can't find any documentation about how to specify string length when creating a DataFrame. What is the solution here?

Update:

Code that is failing:

```
        store = pd.HDFStore(pytables_store)            
        for test in self.backtests:
            try:
                min_itemsizes = { 'buy_pattern' : 60, 'sell_pattern': 60, 'strategy': 60, 'title': 60 }
                store.append('tests', test.export_as_df(), min_itemsize = min_itemsizes)
```

Here's the error under 0.11rc1:

```
File "<ipython-input-110-492b7b6603d7>", line 522, in save_pytables
  store.append('tests', test.export_as_df(), min_itemsize = min_itemsizes)
File "/Users/admin/dev/pandas/pandas-0.11.0rc1/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 610, in append
  self._write_to_group(key, value, table=True, append=True, **kwargs)
File "/Users/admin/dev/pandas/pandas-0.11.0rc1/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 871, in _write_to_group
  s.write(obj = value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
File "/Users/admin/dev/pandas/pandas-0.11.0rc1/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2707, in write
  min_itemsize=min_itemsize, **kwargs)
File "/Users/admin/dev/pandas/pandas-0.11.0rc1/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2447, in create_axes
  self.validate_min_itemsize(min_itemsize)
File "/Users/admin/dev/pandas/pandas-0.11.0rc1/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2184, in validate_min_itemsize
  raise ValueError("min_itemsize has [%s] which is not an axis or data_column" % k)
ValueError: min_itemsize has [buy_pattern] which is not an axis or data_column
```

Data sample:

```
                           all_day              buy_pattern  \
2013-04-14 12:11:44.377695   False  Hammer() and LowerLow()   

                                                           id instrument  \
2013-04-14 12:11:44.377695  tafdcc96ba4eb11e2a86d14109fcecd49     EURUSD   

                            open_margin periodicity sell_pattern strategy  \
2013-04-14 12:11:44.377695       0.0001     1:00:00                 Tsl()   

                           title  top_bottom  wick_body  
2013-04-14 12:11:44.377695   tsl         0.5          2
```

dtypes:

```
print prob_test.export_as_df().get_dtype_counts() 

    bool       1
    float64    2
    int64      1
    object     7
    dtype: int64
```

I am deleting the h5 file each time as I want clean results. Wondering if there is something as silly as it is failing because the df does not exist in the h5 (and hence neither do any columns) at the time of the first append?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#notes-caveats, I suppose should put in a separate section. You need to a-priori specify your the max length of strings you want to have, e.g. ``min_itemsize = 100`` or you can do separately for each column, see doc ref, also this may be a useful reference: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#hdfstore, specificall the Trouble HDFStore exception

Comment: here's another example: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#storing-mixed-types-in-a-table

Comment: Thanks for coming back so fast! Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work for me - I'm passing in a dictionary:


         `min_itemsizes = { 'bp' : 60, 'sp': 60, 'st': 60, 'title': 60 }`
         `store.append('tests', test.export_as_df(), min_itemsize = min_itemsizes)`

Still getting just the same error!

I tried just setting an integer, but this failed (I presume) because not all of the fields are strings. I'm on Pandas 10.1.

Comment: try using 0.11rc1 (just came out yest). there r changes in the way min_itemsize is handled, and error messages r better - it maybe failing somewhere else - that is more of a catch all message. pls post df.get_dtype_counts() along with a data sample if u can

Comment: Updated with the new error under 0.11rc1 (above)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the link to the new docs section about this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#string-columns

This issue is that you are specifiying a column in min_itemsize that is not a data_column. Simple workaround is to add `data_columns=True` to your append statement, but I have also updated the code to automatically create the data_columns if you pass a valid column name. I think this makes sense, you want to have a minimum column size, so let it happen.

Also created a new doc section String Columns to show a more complete example with explanation (docs will be updated soon).

```
# this is the new behavior (after code updates)
n [340]: dfs = DataFrame(dict(A = 'foo', B = 'bar'),index=range(5))

In [341]: dfs
Out[341]: 
     A    B
0  foo  bar
1  foo  bar
2  foo  bar
3  foo  bar
4  foo  bar

# A and B have a size of 30
In [342]: store.append('dfs', dfs, min_itemsize = 30)

In [343]: store.get_storer('dfs').table
Out[343]: 
/dfs/table (Table(5,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": StringCol(itemsize=30, shape=(2,), dflt='', pos=1)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (963,)
  autoIndex := True
  colindexes := {
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False}

# A is created as a data_column with a size of 30
# B is size is calculated
In [344]: store.append('dfs2', dfs, min_itemsize = { 'A' : 30 })

In [345]: store.get_storer('dfs2').table
Out[345]: 
/dfs2/table (Table(5,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": StringCol(itemsize=3, shape=(1,), dflt='', pos=1),
  "A": StringCol(itemsize=30, shape=(), dflt='', pos=2)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (1598,)
  autoIndex := True
  colindexes := {
    "A": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False}
```

Comment: Yep, that has fixed it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I updated with a link to the new String Column section in the docs, and added this question to the cookbook

Comment: how do you set the min_itemsize for a column that is part of the index? I get: AttributeError: "'Index' object has no attribute 'extend'"