# How to handle min_itemsize exception in writing to pandas HDFStore

Tags: python-3.x, exception, pandas, dataframe, hdfstore

I am using pandas HDFStore to store dfs which I have created from data.

```
store = pd.HDFStore(storeName, ...)
for file in downloaded_files:
    try:
        with gzip.open(file) as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            df = json_normalize(data)   
            store.append(storekey, df, format='table', append=True)
    except TypeError:
        pass
        #File Error
```

I have received the error:

```
ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [82] in [values_block_2] column but
this column has a limit of [72]!
Consider using min_itemsize to preset the sizes on these columns
```

I found that it is possible to set min_itemsize for the column involved but this is not a viable solution as I do not know the max length I will encounter and all the columns which I will encounter the problem.

Is there a solution to automatically catch this exception and handle it each item it occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

```
store.append(storekey, df, format='table', append=True, min_itemsize={'Long_string_column': 200})
```

basically it's very similar to the following `create table` SQL statement:

```
create table df(
  id     int,
  str    varchar(200)
);
```

where 200 is the **maximal** allowed length for the `str` column

The following links might be very helpful:

https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+ValueError%3A+Trying+to+store+a+string+with+len+in+column+but+min_itemsize&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr

[HDFStore.append(string, DataFrame) fails when string column contents are longer than those already there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988871/hdfstore-appendstring-dataframe-fails-when-string-column-contents-are-longer)

[Pandas pytable: how to specify min_itemsize of the elements of a MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710738/pandas-pytable-how-to-specify-min-itemsize-of-the-elements-of-a-multiindex)